# What is the best way to write SQL for the problem stated below

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table x with column called `Sprint` that looks like below(note that I am just showing one row from this table as an example):

| Sprint |
| --- |
| ["com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@55efff25[id=4659,rapidViewId=422,state=CLOSED,name=Sprint 108,startDate=2020-12-22T21:48:00.000-06:00,endDate=2021-01-04T21:48:00.000-06:00,completeDate=2021-01-05T01:28:18.156-06:00,activatedDate=2020-12-23T03:01:14.201-06:00,sequence=4658,goal=,autoStartStop=false]"] |

I need help writing SQL to extract `name`, `startDate` and `endDate` as separate columns in a view where the output would look like as listed below;

| Name | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sprint 108 | 2020-12-22T21:48:00.000-06:00 | 2021-01-04T21:48:00.000-06:00 |

Comment: Is that all one field? Can you change the data structure before going too far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(SPRINT, ',', 4),'=',2) as Name,
 SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(SPRINT, ',', 5),'=',2) as StartDate,
 SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(SPRINT, ',', 6),'=',2) as EndDate
FROM x;
```

This is one solution to the above problem that gives the output;

| Name | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sprint 108 | 2020-12-22T21:48:00.000-06:00 | 2021-01-04T21:48:00.000-06:00 |

Answer (score 2):

you can try using REGEXP_INSTR as below done for a name column.

```
select column1,
REGEXP_INSTR(column1, 'name=') name_start,
REGEXP_INSTR(column1, ',',REGEXP_INSTR(column1, 'name=') ) name_end,
substr(column1,name_start,name_end-name_start)
from values
('com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@55efff25[id=4659,rapidViewId=422,state=CLOSED,name=Sprint 108,startDate=2020-12-22T21:48:00.000-06:00,endDate=2021-01-04T21:48:00.000-06:00,completeDate=2021-01-05T01:28:18.156-06:00,activatedDate=2020-12-23T03:01:14.201-06:00,sequence=4658,goal=,autoStartStop=false]');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  SPLIT_PART(SPRINT, ',', 4) as Name,
  SPLIT_PART(SPRINT, ',', 5) as StartDate,
  SPLIT_PART(SPRINT, ',', 6) as EndDate,
FROM x;
```

I tried this and it worked Just need to clean the column and change data type.